# Inserting an empty Facebook comment

Tags: facebook, blank-line

[This](https://www.facebook.com/memeskilledmyfamily/posts/1177909065586454?comment_id=1177950175582343) seems to be a completely empty Facebook comment. Comments consisting solely of newlines or spaces are not allowed, but a blank comment can be made by inserting a soft hyphen (via ALT 0173). However, unlike the comment in the link, a soft hyphen comment is still "selectable" by dragging over it, and leaves a trace in the html.

Blank soft hyphen comment:

```
<span class="UFICommentBody"><span>&shy;</span></span>
```

The empty comment:

```
<span class="UFICommentBody"></span>
```

Some tutorials suggest typing @[0:0: ], but Facebook inserts a space between the "@" and "[".

So how would one go about doing this?

[An empty comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVEa3.png)

**EDIT**:

Typing "@[0:0]" from the Facebook **Android App** results only in a "0". Typing "@[0:]", however, seems to produce no comment whatsoever, but perhaps there is a workaround?

Comment: _“So how would one go about doing this?”_ – not at all, perhaps? What would be the point of posting empty comments?

Comment: I'm just curious as to how it works.